# Creating a Technic launcher button

Tags: bash, minecraft

I have downloaded Technic, and the launcher works. I then proceeded to make a baSH script, which also works. I have now tried to make a launcher button for Technic, and it appears in my menu (I use Gnome3, and it appears in the Activities menu), but, whenever I click on the launcher, it tells me that the script to run Technic isn't in the directory I specified, even though it clearly is.

technic.sh (modified minecraft.sh script):

```
#!bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0/lib/amd64'
#/usr/java/latest/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp TechnicLauncher.jar org.spoutcraft.launcher.entrypoint.Start launch
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -jar TechnicLauncher.jar
```

Technic.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Technic
Comment=Technic
Exec=/home/tony/Technic/technic.sh
Icon=/home/tony/Technic/Technic.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

technic.sh is in my Technic folder in my home directory. Technic.desktop is in my .local/share/applications folder, as per [these  instructions](http://www.https://askubuntu.com/questions/296741/how-to-create-the-minecraft-launcher-button).

The exact error is:

```
Failed to launch 'Technic'
Failed to execute child process '/home/tony/Technic/technic.sh': no such file or directory
```

Comment: What happens when you run `cat /home/tony/Technic/technic.sh` in the command line?

Comment: `#!bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0/lib/amd64'
#/usr/java/latest/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp TechnicLauncher.jar org.spoutcraft.launcher.entrypoint.Start launch
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -jar TechnicLauncher.jar
` I issued the command from ~/.local/share/applications

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this .desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Technic Launcher
Comment=Minecraft
Exec=/usr/java/latest/bin/java -jar /home/tony/Technic/TechnicLauncher.jar
Icon=/home/tony/Technic/Technic.png
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Categories=Game;
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your answer. To put things in `code markdown`, indent them by four spaces. BTW if you disagree with my edit, you can roll it back. Click on the "edited ... ago" above my icon. That takes you to the edit history, where you will find a rollback button.